# Query "where clause" fails when calling a function

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a function in Access VBA that takes four parameters.The fourth parameter is a "where clause" that I use in an SQL statement inside the function. The function fails when I include the fourth parameter (where clause). When I remove this fourth parameter, the function just works fine. I am not sure if there is anything wrong with the syntax of the fourth parameter ? Please help. here is the function as called in the Query

```
FunctionA('Table1','Field1',0.3,'Field2=#' & [Field2] & '# and Value3="' & [Value3] & '"') AS Duration_Field
```

Comment: Value3 are characters. examples: XX, YY, AY, and so on.

Comment: You seem to me to be reversing the meaning of the ' and " quotes. Normally, you'd use " to delimite string values passed as arguments to a function.

Answer (score 2):

I would split Field2 and Value3 out into separate parameters for your function. Passing parameters like that is just asking for trouble.

I'd rewrite the function along these lines:

```
FunctionA('Table1','Field1',0.3,'Field2','Value3') AS Duration_Field
```

Then handle the combining of the parameters in the function itself instead of in the function call.